# Whitelist the outbound IP address of an Azure Web App in the Azure SQL server firewall settings using ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-rm-template, whitelist, azure-sql-server

I want to whitelist the outbound IP address of my Azure Web App in the firewall settings of the Azure sql server using Arm templates.
However, I do not want to hardcode the start and end Ip addresses in the ARM template.
Is there a way of dynamically adding the Ip addresses in the firewall settings at runtime?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: https://blog.petergerritsen.nl/2019/01/28/arm-whitelist-outbound-ips-from-another-app-service

Comment: this is exactly your scenario https://aztoso.com/arm%20templates/arm-nightmare-reference/

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://aztoso.com/arm%20templates/arm-nightmare-reference/) describes exactly your scenario. However, have you rather considered using Regional [VNET integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration) for your App Service and then using a Subnet-based firewall rule in the SQL DB? I would rather recommend the second solution.